# Error Calculating the Angle Moved using Computer Vision

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, trigonometry, angle

I am running deep learning object detection for tracking one person in a space using OpenCV, SingleShot Detector and MobileNets. I am writing in Python. I need to calculate the angle traveled when the person moves from one position to another.

I have written an algorithm that first calculates the centroid of the detected person using the bounding box dimensions. Next it calculates the distance to the person using a formula obtained using regression. With that done, the values generated are compared with previous values, and their horizontal distances are calculated. For each instance therefore, the current distance, the previous distance and the horizontal distance between them form a triangle with known sides. It is therefore possible to calculate the angle traveled, which is essentially the angle between the lines representing the previous distance and the current distance, using the Cosine Rule. I did this in my algorithm for the various possible scenarios.

```py
if CLASSES[idx] == "person":
    heig = endY-startY
    wid = endX-startX
    currDistance = 23.0591-(0.0686*heig)
    currCentX = (startX + (endX / 2.0))
    currCentY = (startY + (endY / 2.0))
    if initValues > 0:
        if (prevCentX > currCentX):
            if (prevCentY == currCentY):
                horizDistMoved = abs((prevCentX-currCentX))
                angle = degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
            elif (prevCentY < currCentY):
                horizDistMoved = hypot((prevCentX-currCentX),(currCentY-prevCentY))
                angle = degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
            elif (prevCentY > currCentY):
                horizDistMoved = hypot((prevCentX-currCentX),(prevCentY-currCentY))
                angle = degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
            elif (prevCentX == currCentX):
                horizDistMoved = 0
                angle = 0
            elif (prevCentX < currCentX):
                if (prevCentY == currCentY):
                    horizDistMoved = abs((currCentX-prevCentX))
                    angle = degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
                elif (prevCentY < currCentY):
                    horizDistMoved = hypot((currCentX-prevCentX),(currCentY-prevCentY))
                    angle = degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
                elif (prevCentY > currCentY):
                    horizDistMoved = hypot((currCentX-prevCentX),(prevCentY-currCentY))
                    angle = degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
            print("Angle is " +str(angle))
        else:
            time.sleep(0.2)
        prevCentX = currCentX
        prevCentY = currCentY
        prevDistance = currDistance
        initValues += 1
```

I expected a print out of angles as the person moves. However, each time I move, the algorithm crashes with the error below. This happens on different lines depending on my position.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Navigation+Servo_lite.py", line 146, in <module>
     angle = degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
ValueError: math domain error
```

I think for some reason, the expression making up the divisor keeps being equal to zero. I would appreciate any suggestions on what may be wrong and how to improve it or if there is an alternative way to go about calculating the angle.

The entire code block is longer than the above but if required, I can include that as well.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried np arccos . numpy.arccos
numpy.arccos(x[, out]) = <ufunc 'arccos'>
Trigonometric inverse cosine, element-wise.
The inverse of cos so that, if y = cos(x), then x = arccos(y).

Comment: also can you separate each operation in degrees(acos(((currDistance**2 + prevDistance**2)-(horizDistMoved**2))/(2*currDistance*prevDistance)))
. to find out exactly where is the problem? when it comes to divie, it is safe practise to determine whether the bottom is 0 or not.